# Mounting a Pull Up Bar

Tags: wood

Due to quarantine, I can no longer go out and exercise, so I am looking to drill a pull up bar in my room.

I can either drill the bar in the wall or the ceiling, both which is made of wood. This is my first DIY project ever, so I don't know if they can support my weight when I hang on a bar, and I am unsure where to drill the holes.

Do I drill it directly in the wood or are there metal studs?

I am also worried the screws might damage the structural integrity of the wood. Any suggestions for where to drill in either the wall or the ceiling?
Edit: People are asking for pictures so I will include pictures.

This is a wall that I can put the pull up bar, or on the ceiling.

[image]

I can also put the pull up bar on the wall here.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add more info, and perhaps pictures of your walls/ceilings? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Your first DIY project ever should not be one involving human safety rating.   Your walls and ceiling are NOT made of wood.  They are made of drywall, which is - well, mix Elmers glue and water 50/50 and soak a strip of newspaper in it. Wrap it around a piece of chalk and let it dry.  *That's drywall*.

Comment: Despite the warnings (and they are _very_ valid) this is certainly doable. You just need to take care - asking for advice is a _great_ first step.

Comment: Michael, We need to know what brand/model number of pull up bar you have or photos of it so we know how it mounts in order to give a specific answer. Also, **use the search function** of this site to search "pull up bar" as there are many questions with good advise on mounting options.

Comment: Hey Alaska Man and Daniel Griscom, I don't know how to reply to a comment since this is my first day here, but I have not picked out a pull up bar yet since I want to make sure how to properly install it first and see it the pull up bar I will choose will be compatible with my wall.

Comment: @MichaelKwan if you'll take the [tour], you'll learn nifty tricks like hitting `@` then starting to type a user's name, you can then select from the options that pop up (be sure to click the name, the formatting can be different than what's displayed) in order to "ping" a user so they know you're talking to them.

Comment: @BigMike - We can not really give you the correct answer until we know what the mounting requirements are. Perhaps you can find one or two on the internet and use the edit button to put the links in the question and we can see if they will work on your  wall. Your wall appears to be a "normal" wall with drywall over studs that should be spaced 16 inch's apart. (*on center*)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, congrats on taking up your first ever DIY project! It will be a rewarding experience. The more you do, the more you will learn and enrich your life, as well as being able to help those around you.

For the wall option, you'd want to go into the studs, which you can find with a studfinder, or just watch a video on how to find them by knocking on the drywall. Knocking on drywall to find them is very easy.

The screws you use shouldn't compromise the structural integrity of the wood; whatever you're mounting, you shouldn't have to use anything more than a wood screw that's a couple inches long.

I wouldn't try to install on the ceiling; seems like you'd hit your head on the ceiling before you'd complete a full range of motion for a pull-up. Installing one in the wall, over a doorway is ideal. That way your body can swing forward slightly when performing the motion, and you should still have enough headroom.

My favorite training tool for rock climbing is called a "hangboard". They allow various different types of strength building compared to a pull-up bar, but you can still do pull-ups on them. They have a very easy-to-follow install guide on their site.

Here's a link to one online: https://www.metoliusclimbing.com/project-board.html

That being said, you could also just get a removable one: [link](https://www.target.com/p/ignite-by-spri-pull-up-bar-black/-/A-77755215?ref=tgt_adv_XS000000&AFID=google_pla_df&fndsrc=tgtao&CPNG=PLA_Sports%2BShopping_Local&adgroup=SC_Sports_Local&LID=700000001170770pgs&network=g&device=c&location=9030070&ds_rl=1246978&ds_rl=1248099&gclid=CjwKCAjwzvX7BRAeEiwAsXExo82AEFSYegukyMuDd6xkkdaS0EuFleKe4_Ae66P1Y1W-au1UoRRV0hoC7FcQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)
I used to have one of these when I lived in an apartment, and didn't want to have to resurface walls after moving out. Be warned though, if you get a removeable one, you can't pull as hard/move as fast, for it can bounce and come loose. Also, if the walls and ceiling are wood, I'd go with this option as defacing a nice looking wooden wall is a little sacrilege IMO.

Best of luck!

Comment: I mostly agree with you about the mountings not damaging the studs, however, if the bar comes with large lag bolts, there could be some concern, especially if they're not centered exactly in the studs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a pull up bar that goes in a door frame?  These are relatively inexpensive, and go inside the door frame, and push outward against both sides of the door frame.  They rely on friction, not screws and take about 5 minutes to install.

I put one in one of my door frames years ago, and it's worked perfectly.

Comment: yeah but i am looking to do muscle ups or wide grip pull ups, and my door frame is not wide enough or tall enough